# "Show X more comments" link appears even when there is nothing to be shown

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-comments, user-experience

My flag *"It's no longer needed"* was accepted for four comments under this question: [Safeness of changing proto field number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230623/safeness-of-changing-proto-field-number)

After deletion, when I revisited the post, it showed **"Show 2 more comments"** under the question's two comments.
But there were only two comments in total to be shown!

[image]

Such a link might be useful for the moderators, who can still view the deleted comments. However, for the normal users it shouldn't be shown, as it doesn't make any sense.